# Is there any way to limit error logging to Appinsight when trying to connect to deleted cosmos db

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-application-insights

I am using azure cosmos db to save some data. I cannot change the connection string and all the other detail of Azure cosmos db in the application.

In case Azure cosmos db is deleted i have added one try catch block to catch the exception whenever a try is made to connect to azure cosmosdb and logging it into azure AppInsight telemetry.

But, while logging this exception i am also getting multiple `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` logged.

I tried to debug the code but cannot find the root place for this exception plus as exception is getting logged into azure appinsight with some delay i am not able to pinpoint the place where it is getting generated.

What I want to do is minimize the logging of same exception or ignore it if possible.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you add the output in your log in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can filter the telemetry using a `TelemetryProcessor`. See [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling).

Here is an example that exclude *all* SocketException from the logging. You can write your own logic to decide what to exclude.

```cs
public class ExceptionTelemetryFilter : ITelemetryProcessor
    {
        private readonly ITelemetryProcessor _next;

        public ExceptionTelemetryFilter(ITelemetryProcessor next)
        {
            _next = next;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Exclude SocketException from logging
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="item"></param>
        public void Process(ITelemetry item)
        {
            if(!(item is ExceptionTelemetry exception)  // If it is not an exception
               || !(exception.Exception is SocketException)) // or it is not a SocketException
                _next.Process(item); // then log the item by sending it down the processing pipeline
        }
    }
```

The take away is that, if you want to exclude an item from logging, you should *not* call `_next.Process(item)`.

Now, include it in the services collection so it is known by Application Insights. For .Net Core this is done like this:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryProcessor<ExceptionTelemetryFilter>();

            ...
        }
```

Note: how to register the processor is determined by the kind of app. See the linked documentation on top for the options.